# Why groovy is called mostly dynamic language?

Tags: java, groovy, dynamic-languages

When reviewing Paul King's slide share of Groovy , i found groovy is called mostly dynamic. I always thought groovy is a duck type dynamic language. Is some part of the groovy is not so dynamic?

http://www.slideshare.net/paulk_asert/groovy-tutorial

Comment: Can you point to where it's been called that?

Comment: I first saw this on Paul King's slide share presentation, and maybe some other places i can not remember.

http://www.slideshare.net/paulk_asert/groovy-tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called a mostly dynamic language due to the static type checking introduced in 2.0.

See: [What’s new in Groovy 2.0?](http://www.infoq.com/articles/new-groovy-20)